# Why did this if check pass?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I'm checking if `$location.$$url` is `!= 'dashboard'` however this statement is true, yet it continues.

```
// the URL is currently at /dashboard
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard") 
    console.log('Custome URL found!');
    vs.customURL = true;
    TagFactory.buildUrlObject($location.$$url);
```

You can see the `console.log` print out `/dashboard` below:
[image]

And here too I'm checking the `$location` and `$$url` is `"/dashboard"` so the `if` statement should be skipped, yet it continues?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us your code in text format?

Comment: Your indents seem to suggest that you expect the subsequent statements to be governed by the `if` statement, but you don't have any curly braces. Maybe it's just sloppy formatting though. To be clear, Javascript != Python

Comment: Be more clear about what you expect to (not) happen. Post actual code not screenshots.  Near as I can tell from your screenshots, the condition is NOT executing (I don't see "Custome URL found!" console log).  Perhaps you mean some code after that is executing? Perhaps you need to wrap the code in  `{...}` to be part of the `if` block? Be more clear.

Comment: @spender ah, so that's the case then... I like the formatting without `{}` it looks better imho, more like Python, cleaner... did not realize it's not the same.

Comment: Unlike Python, in most other languages, indentation means nothing to the compiler/interpreter. Without the braces, the "group" only consists of the first expression after the condition. So you have to group multiple expressions with braces.

Comment: I tend to always place braces, even for one-liners, because it's less likely to lead to mistakes down the road, especially if you're chopping and changing between languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments state, your missing curly braces.

Try changing it to the following so that the statements are contained within the condition.

```
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard") {
    console.log('Custome URL found!');
    vs.customURL = true;
    TagFactory.buildUrlObject($location.$$url);
}
```

---

Without curly braces an if statement is a single statement. For example you could do:

```
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard") alert("not dashboard");
```

Or

```
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard"){
   alert("not dashboard");
   //Additional statements here
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation! I just recently discovered that you could write Javascript without `{}` and started to change it up in a few places, I must have skipped over the 1-line requirement for that style. 7 mins!

Answer (score 2):

You can ommit the curly braces (`{}`) for only one line after a `if` statement.
Your code should be:

```
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard") {
    console.log('Custome URL found!');
    vs.customURL = true;
    TagFactory.buildUrlObject($location.$$url);
}
```

Also, it's generally not considered best practice to ommit curly braces, exactly because of this situation.

Comment: Thanks as well! Yeah, will only use that for 1-line statements now, was trying to optimize everywhere, but gotta stick to readability...

Answer (score 1):

I think @spender already gave the answer, the curly brace is missing:

```
if ($location.$$url !== "/dashboard") {
    console.log('Custome URL found!');
    vs.customURL = true;
    TagFactory.buildUrlObject($location.$$url);
}
```